# One Proof question in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that if $A$ has a rank $r$ with $r > 0$, then $A$ has an $r \times r$ invertible submatrix.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to start. I have all kinds of definitions and notes, but it doesn't help.

Comment: If you have no more questions about the answer, you should accept it. Otherwise your OP is listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The number $r$ is the number of pivots in the RREF. So it cannot be bigger than the number of columns or the number of rows in the matrix.

If $r$ is smaller then the number of rows we can delete one row and proceed by induction on the number of rows. So $r$ is the number of rows.

Similarly $r$ is the number of columns.

So we have a square matrix of maximal rank. Then its deterrminant is not $0$.

Comment: Good point, I have an idea how to start. Thank you

Comment: The answer contains a complete proof.

Comment: Yeah, thank you.

Comment: "proceed by induction on the number of rows. So r is the number of rows." I don't quite understand how this works.

Comment: The logic of this proof is fine

Comment: No $r$ is the rank. If the matrix is $m\times n$ and $r<m$ then you can remove a  row  without changing the rank. Then by induction the new matrix has an $r\times r$-submatrix $M$ with non-zero determinant. That $M$ is a submatrix of the original matrix too.

Comment: The logic is completely correct.

Comment: I am afraid that just say "by induction" something something... is not a strict proof

Comment: It is a strict proof. Since I do not know your level, I just assumed that you can understand it. I did give some more details in the comment above.

Comment: I do understand the logic completely as a whole, but not the induction part, I know exactly how induction works, but I think I need to write it out explicitly in this proof. So your comment above says "Then by induction the new matrix has an r×r-submatrix M with non-zero determinant," can you say something more about it? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you have not seen many proofs by induction it is a good idea to write a formal proof here with bases, steps of induction and so on.

Comment: I think I got it.